# ¿Por qué cuando presiono enter se actualiza mi página?

Tags: java, html, oracle, mvc, weblogic

Tengo una *aplicación web* en *JavaEE*, y tengo un recuadro en el cual realizo una búsqueda mediante el botón buscar... Lo curioso es que cuando presiono *enter*, en vez de buscar en la base de datos del servidor, se actualiza o *"limpia"* la tabla que debería mostrar mis resultados. Con *click* sí, cumple su función, pero claro, por el evento *ON click*. ¿Por qué sucede esa actualización?

Dejo el fragmento del código en donde se encuentra el botón buscar, al cual se le hace *click* para poder realizar la misma:

```
/*...*/
        <input
            type="text"
            name="buscarProductoInput"
            id="buscarProductoInput"
            class="busquedaLarga_input ui-corner-all"
            onchange="informacionProducto()"/>
        </span>

        <div align="left">
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#radio").buttonset();
                });
            </script>

            <div id="radio" class="check">
                <input name="radio" type="radio" id="radio1" checked="checked"/>
                <label for="radio1"> Producto&nbsp; </label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="radio2"
                    name="radio"
                />
                <label for="radio2">PromociÃ³n&nbsp; </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a href="#" onclick="informacionProducto()" class="buscar">Buscar</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="limpiarTablas()" class="buscar">Limpiar</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="IpCC" id="IpCC" value="" class=""/>

        <div id="loading">
            <p>Buscando producto,</p>

            <p> por favor, espere ... </p>

            <p>
                <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading" width="46" height="47"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="banner_adds"></div>
```

Comment: Comparte el código para que podamos verlo e identificar cualquier posible causa. Sin código es bastante difícil porque puede deberse a diferentes cosas

Comment: Alvaro Montoro ya realize la edicion con el codigo correspondiente a el metodo que realiza la busqueda en la BD y el codigo al hacer clic al boton buscar, espero puedas ayudarme

Answer (score 1):

Lo que planteas puede deberse a varias cosas, lo mejor es que presentes todo el código de la página con la que trabajas. Pero aun así, aquí te dejo cosas a tener en cuenta:

- Si usas formularios, recuerda que los mismos por defecto al "submitear", envían la petición al servidor y refrescan la página (es decir, volverá a cargarla). Con solo hacer Enter, esto ocurre y te puede limpiar la página.
- Chequea que no exista alguna función javascript que programe la ejecución de algún botón en la página al presionar Enter.
- Si estás haciendo foco sobre un botón y haces Enter, el mismo será ejecutado.

Presupongo que tu caso puede ser la primera opción que te listé, y por lo que note de tu código, estás queriendo hacer que el formulario sea AJAX (realice una petición asincrónica con javascript).

Aunque no sepa si este es tu caso. Te dejo debajo un formulario AJAX sin validación de campos para que veas cómo funciona.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input
        type="text"
        name="buscarProductoInput"
        id="buscarProductoInput"
        class="busquedaLarga_input ui-corner-all"
        onchange="informacionProducto()"/>
    </span>

    <div align="left">
        <script>

        </script>

        <div id="radio" class="check">
            <input name="radio" type="radio" id="radio1" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="radio1"> Producto&nbsp; </label>
            <input
                type="radio"
                id="radio2"
                name="radio"
            />
            <label for="radio2">Promoción&nbsp; </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" onclick="limpiarTablas()" class="buscar">Limpiar</a>

    <input type="hidden" name="IpCC" id="IpCC" value="" class=""/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="informacionProducto()" value="Buscar"></input>
</form>
```

Observa que agregué esto `onsubmit="return false;"`, y de esta forma indico que el formulario no se *"submitea"*, impidiendo el refresco de la página. También cambié el link "buscar" por este botón de *submit* `<input type="submit" onclick="informacionProducto()" value="Buscar"></input>`. De esta forma, tanto al hacer click sobre el botón como presionar Enter, se disparará la función `informacionProducto()`.

Comment: okey amigo muchas gracias dejame probarlo y te estare notificando, caso contrario dejare todo el codigo con los script

Comment: amigo muchas gracias funciono a la perfeccion, solo me toca estilizar el boton y listo un millon!

Comment: Me alegro mucho! Saludos.